# ?attr in drawable resource causing Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, drawable, attr

In a layer list I used solid in some items and set color using `?attr/text_color`.

`<stroke android:color="?attr/text_color" />`

and set this drawable as background of a button. `android:background="@drawable/myLayerListDrawable"`

I was using this without any problem until I run this project on a lower api `18`.

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/myLayerListDrawable.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080063
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to
>   color: type=0x2

Why is this happening and how this can be resolved !?

**res\drawable\myLayerListDrawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <selector>
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="?attr/background_button_pressed" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="0.7dp"
                    android:color="?attr/text_color" />

                <corners android:radius="10dp" />

            </shape>
        </item>


        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="0.7dp"
                    android:color="?attr/text_color" />

                <corners android:radius="10dp" />

            </shape>
        </item>


    </selector>


</item>
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Final Answer**

> We can't use ?attr in xml drawable resources pre api 21. Drawable
>   resources created by aapt in compile time. Attr resources used for
>   dynamic connection in runtime.

And the solution is to create different drawbles for every theme.

Comment: It should be **`<stroke android:color="@color/myColor" />`**

Comment: @NileshRathod I'm using different color for different themes

Comment: ok but you can not access color like  `"?attr/myColor"`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a reference into your styles or attr file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <!-- Attributes must be lowercase as we want to use them for drawables -->
   <attr name="myColor" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

and add this to your theme:

```
<item name="myColor">#c3c3c3</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access your color resource  like `"?attr/myColor`

For more information read

- [What does ?attr/ mean on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165168/what-does-attr-mean-on-android)
- [App resources overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#Accessing)

Use

```
<stroke android:color="@color/myColor" />
```

Instead of

```
<stroke android:color="?attr/myColor" />
```

and make sure your have added `myColor` in **res/values/colors.XML**

Comment: How do you use theme based color in drawable resource?

Comment: @Mehran check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735675/change-drawable-based-on-theme

Comment: @Mehran test case try this way `android:color="?myColor"`

Comment: You are right. referencing color in drawables cannot be done in pre `API 21`. And the solution is to create different drawbles for every theme.