# What's the difference between `?colorPrimary` and `?attr/colorPrimary`

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I've been checking some Material Theming examples recently and I found the usage of `?colorPrimary` instead of `?attr/colorPrimary` is there any difference between them?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38165203/1631967

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I'm not asking about the difference between `?android:attr/colorPrimary` and `?attr/colorPrimary`

Comment: You can check the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ReferencesToThemeAttributes): *Because the system resource tool knows that an attribute resource is expected in this context, you do not need to explicitly state the type—you can exclude the attr type*